# python zeroconf show IPv4 addresses

Tags: python, ipv4, zeroconf

I'm trying to figure out how to scan the network for devices which are published by avahi.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from zeroconf import ServiceBrowser, Zeroconf
from time import sleep

class MyListener:
    def remove_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        print("Service % removed" % (name))

    def add_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        info = zeroconf.get_service_info(type, name)
        info = str(info)
        info = info.split(",")[6]
        print(info)


zeroconf = Zeroconf()
listener = MyListener()
browser = ServiceBrowser(zeroconf, "_http._tcp.local.", listener)
try:
        sleep(1)
finally:
        zeroconf.close()
```

It works, but it doesn't give me ANY IPv4 address.
Output(example):

> ServiceInfo(type='_http._tcp.local.', name='Barco
>   ptp-owsserver-2237._http._tcp.local.', address=b'\n\x80Cj', port=80,
>   weight=0, priority=0, server='ptp-owsserver-2237.local.',
>   properties={b'root': b'/'})

Could PLEASE someone tell me how to get the IPv4 Addresses of the devices which are published by avahi in our network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the IP addresses, you can use the attribute `address` of class `ServiceInfo`. It gives you the IP address in `bytes` type (in your post, it is displayed as `b'\n\x80Cj'`), so that you should use `socket.inet_ntoa()` to convert it to a more readable format. Here is the code where I replaced the `print()` instruction in the `MyListener.add_service()` method in order to print the IP address:

```
from zeroconf import ServiceBrowser, Zeroconf
import socket

class MyListener:

    def remove_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        print("Service %s removed" % (name,))

    def add_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        info = zeroconf.get_service_info(type, name)
        if info: 
            #print("Service %s added, service info: %s" % (name, info))
            print("Service %s added, IP address: %s" % (name, socket.inet_ntoa(info.address)))


zeroconf = Zeroconf()
listener = MyListener()
browser = ServiceBrowser(zeroconf, "_http._tcp.local.", listener)
try:
    input("Press enter to exit...\n\n")
finally:
    zeroconf.close()
```

Comment: In my case info contains always a list of addresses. So I had to change the code to `socket.inet_ntoa(info.addresses[0]))`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also get parsed addresses direct from ServiceInfo.

```
print("Service %s added, IP address: %s" % (name, info.parsed_addresses()[0]))
```